# PHP mail() is not sending email

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using the following code for a contact form in HTML:

```
  <form method="post" name="contact_form"
action="contact-form-handler.php" data-add-back-btn="false" data-ajax="false">
    Your Name:
      <span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span> 
      Code:
      <span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input type="text" name="code">
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span> 
      Email Address:
      <span id="sprytextfield2">
      <input type="text" name="email">
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span> Message:
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

That is the PHP file to handle the mail function:

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'email';//<-----Real email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||  empty($_POST['code'])  ||
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message".
"Codigo: $code\n";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

When the user completes the form and clicks on the submit button, the thank you page is opened, but the form isn't emailed.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: have you done ANY basic debugging? checked the return value from mail()? checked your mail server's logs to see what happens after php hands it over?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the issue? Have you checked your error log? Your SMTP comfiguration?

Comment: comment header() function and let us see the error. Make sure you have error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Did you check your Spam box? Is `mail()` available? etc. etc. etc. too many things can go wrong. Running on local machine, WWW? Have you tried a simplified method?

Comment: You do know that you have to set up the mail server for this to work right?

Comment: @MarcB, I am using a shared hosting service, I don't know how to check the mail server's log

Comment: @GigaWatt, I am using a shared hosting service, I don't know how to check the mail server's log

Comment: Most free shared hosting services DO NOT allow you to send mail. Write an email to an admin, to make sure that you are allowed to do that before you try to anything else.

Comment: Your code checks out. (tested) If you're on a free hosted service, chances are they're not making `mail()` available for you.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thank you, I guess I should contact my hosting provider

Comment: You can also try using a conditional statement  `if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){ echo "Mail sent."} else{ echo "There was a problem.";}` if you get the latter, then you'll know there's a problem. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, problem solved, it was a mail server issue. Now it works as expected.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, what do you mean with: One more rep point and you'll be able to use "comments".

Comment: That was aimed at the person who gave the answer, not you. Because answers like that, are considered more of a "comment" and are discouraged to be used in cases like this. Commenting is available when a person reaches 50 rep points.

Comment: You're welcome. 99% of the time, comments usually solve issues, rather than "answers", *per se*. Had "I" given you an "answer", I would've have either been mocked and/or downvoted by my peers. I just won't go there for questions like these. Nothing personal ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mail() returns `true`, then contact your hoster`s customer service

Comment: Thank you, I will contact my hosting provider right now.

Comment: You were right, the problem was at the hosting mail server, now it works like a charm.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I got it :)